# What is the reason for the correlation between screen size and dpi

Tags: android

I'm learning about Android, and I noticed there seems to be a relationship between the size of the device and the pixel density (i.e. dpi). For example a 4.7 inch device might have a xhdpi density while a 3.3 inch device might have a density of ldpi.

Is the reason for the higher resolution (density) on larger screen devices due to technological advances coinciding with Android devices generally getting larger? This is just a hypothesis of mine based on observing tables with the above figures. I would like confirmation of this; otherwise, would know whether there exist technical reasons for the correlation. Please ease my confusion in assuming that this correlation between screen size and dpi is coincidental or technical or both.

Comment: Advances in tech => larger screens. Advances in tech => higher dpi. It's a rough relationship that doesn't hold in every case.

Comment: can you elaborate on the exceptions please?

Comment: As your question is not about programming. Your question would be better asked at [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It really depends on the manufacturer/developer of the device. Android is a pretty versatile OS designed to run on a variety of devices. 
eg. if you are using it on a big screen used to ads, a low dpi might be desired assuming it costs less. 
It really depends on a number of factors: the purpose of the android device, budget etc...

Comment: As for exceptions, it's all over the map. For example, a lot of the earlier tablets were mpdi, while several normal-size phones were hdpi.

Comment: but excluding tablets, TVs, and non-phone form factors, is it generally true that technology advances are the main driver for larger phone sizes having higher resolutions (which I assume is basically equivalent to dpi)?

Comment: I guess I don't see why you'd want a larger phone with lower dpi, unless it's  cheaper or something. Maybe I just answered my own question.

Comment: Technological advances such as Full HD and IPS displays have greatly helped mobile manufacturers in achieving higher dpi with bigger screen sizes since there is more available square inch area.